# Properly adjusting view positioning for the iPhone 5 screen

Tags: ios, uiview

I am updating an app to run on the iPhone 5 screen (while maintaining the old screen size layout as well).

I have a xib file that contains a view controller's main view, with a horizontal scroll view in it as a subview. This scroll view's height gets stretched vertically on the iPhone 5 screen.

I also have three views in the xib (used as pages in the scroll view) that get added to the scroll view. I have set all the struts and springs for the top most views to on. I have set all the struts and springs for the subviews inside these views to off.

My problem is that the subviews do not get positioned correctly on the iPhone 5 screen. Specifically I have an image view that should be positioned near the top of the view that is getting moved to the bottom (underneath the other subviews, when they should not be overlapping at all). Setting the top strut to on on the image view causes it to stay at the top of the view, but I want it moved down proportionally to the change in view height.

In my view controller's viewDidLoad I add the pages to the scroll view like this:

```
_pageOne.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, _scrollView.bounds.size.width, _scrollView.bounds.size.height);
[_scrollView addSubview:_pageOne];

_pageTwo.frame = CGRectMake(320, 0, _scrollView.bounds.size.width, _scrollView.bounds.size.height);
[_scrollView addSubview:_pageTwo];

_pageThree.frame = CGRectMake(640, 0, _scrollView.bounds.size.width, _scrollView.bounds.size.height);
[_scrollView addSubview:_pageThree];
```

The views are set up in the xib for the old screen height. I have checked in the debugger that the scroll view has already been stretched in the viewDidLoad.

How can I get my subviews to reposition correctly?

---

(Moved response to comment to an answer)

Comment: Are you using autoresizing mask or layout contraints?

Comment: Try to set the bottom strut on the image view and turning off all other struts and springs of the image view.

Comment: If I set the bottom strut, upon view resizing the image view stays a fixed vertical distance from the bottom of its superview (the superview being _pageOne in this case). But this isn't the behaviour that I want. I want the image view to reposition itself proportional to the change in height of the superview.

Comment: Then you should turn off all struts and springs.

Comment: That's what I did originally, as stated in the question. I would expect that to work, but instead of being repositioned proportionally farther down the view, the image view was getting moved right to the bottom of its superview, and is behind other subviews in _pageOne, so that they were overlapping each other.

Comment: Post image of you xib and autoresizing mask? =)

Comment: Thanks, I was working on posting the xib file and I think I figured out my issue. I updated my question.

Comment: Cool. It was my next suggestion =) But you figured out it firstly =)

Comment: you can answer your own question, and since you have a solution, you should post it as an answer, and then accept it so that others who may be trying to help answer questions here can see from the questions page that it is answered, and possibly even already accepted, assuming you accept your own answer.

Comment: By the way, I just did something similar in one of my projects, and found it went a lot smoother when the parent view controller sets the children's sizes, not let them do it themselves.

Comment: Thanks john.k.doe, I was waiting to see if anyone offered another answer, but I added my own now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually solved my issue by setting the top and bottom strut on my image view, turning on the vertical spring, and setting the image view's contentMode to UIViewContentModeCenter.

But here is how I had my view set up:

[image]

And here is the result on the iPhone 5.

[image]

I hadn't realized that my image view was right at the top of my view. I tried moving the image view down a little, and turning off all of the struts and springs, and everything started behaving as expected:

[image]
[image]